# Client-side technology for a web-based game

Tags: asp.net, ajax, flash, client-side

I am developing a web-based game (similar to [the ESP game](http://www.gwap.com/gwap/gamesPreview/espgame/)), I am done with the server side SOAP web service (built on ASP.NET), and now I am wondering if I should use Flash (swf) or AJAX for the client side layer of the game. Basically, the client side is a web service client making requests to the web server and receiving back instructions on how to render/update the user interface. Any suggestions or considerations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My 2 cents:

**Html/Css/Javascript (aka AJAX)**

- Plus: No client plugin required - "instant on", so you are open to a wider audience (No need to worry about flash versions etc.)
- Plus: Depending on your skillset, you should be able to get something up and running much faster (assuming you are a web developer not a flash guru)
- Plus: should be easier to maintain as wider number of people available to employ to help out.
- Minus: You are going to be more restricted over the visual design
- Minus: You are going to have to spend more time over cross-browser issues, specifically the design more than anything else

**Flash / Flex**

- Plus: Gives you a much richer design environment in which to work
- Plus: No real need to worry about cross-browser issues.
- Minus: Might not be in your skillset, so will take you longer pickup
- Minus: Requires a plugin (not really a big an issue as it used to be)
- Minus: Bringing someone in to help / maintain could be more costly.

Answer (score 2):

If you ask me, Flash/Flex would be easier to develop, maintain and deploy. Plus, it would be accessible by people on different platforms and browsers. Same could be done with AJAX as well, but with a lot more effort to ensure platform independence.

-- Sri

Comment: I'd argue the converse - AJAX being pretty much a native browser technology, is far more independent than technology supplied by a commercial third party.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Silverlight for the client-side, you can stay in .NET/C# land.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but Silverlight will require an additional plug-in to be installed on the client browser.